# How to get customer id from spinner

Tags: java, android

This is a function that i call customer name from database for spinner. When i select the customer name, i also can obtain customer id. How to do it?

```
 public List<String> getAllUsers(String userID) {
    List<String> userlist = new ArrayList<>();
    String status= "Active";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String query = "select " + COLUMN_Customer_NAME + " from customer where " + COLUMN_Customer_USERID + "='" + userID + "'"+" AND " + COLUMN_Customer_STATUS + "='" + status + "'";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            userlist.add(cursor.getString(0));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return userlist;

}
```

Comment: by adding id to the select .... how else? but ... why? since you have the userId, and use it to find the name???

Answer (score 0):

```
spinner_province.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            province_id = position;
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

by using that , You get a selected item from spinner.

Comment: no, `province_id = id`, not `province_id = position;` - basically `position != id`

Answer (score 0):

create your custom spinner and pass array of names and ids to spinner. and by using selecteditemposition get id from array at that position

Answer (score 0):

create a custom adapter for spinner

```
class customAdapter(context : Context ,items: List<YourUserModel>) :
        ArrayAdapter<YourUserModel>(context, resourceID)
```

with custom adapter on item click u can get the full object with will be holding name,id etc etc..

easier but not recommended way u can add the objects to hashmap or arraylist with the index/id of spinner position . then you can get it from there