# How to get customer id of selected value from spinner

Tags: java, android

I want to get the id of the value selected in the spinner. For example when i add new customer, the customer name is "jack" and id is "4". Then i can select customer name - "jack in spinner", how to get id "4".

The Database:

```
 public List<String> getAllUsers(String userID) {
    List<String> userlist = new ArrayList<>();
    String status= "Active";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String query = "select " + COLUMN_Customer_NAME + " from customer where " + COLUMN_Customer_USERID + "='" + userID + "'"+" AND " + COLUMN_Customer_STATUS + "='" + status + "'";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            userlist.add(cursor.getString(0));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return userlist;

}
```

The implementation code:

```
 prepareData();

    allusers.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // clicked item will be shown as spinner
            value = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            custid = position;
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });

 public void prepareData()
{
    users=databaseHelper.getAllUsers(user_id2);
    //adapter for spinner
    adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(AddMobRepairActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,android.R.id.text1,users);
    //attach adapter to spinner
    allusers.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: make custom spinner and pass both name and id to spinner adapter

Comment: You need to have a model(java pojo) to keep all the fields u want. And use that to show data in spinner based on that u can get the corresponding custid

Comment: I assume this is related to this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46090849/how-to-get-customer-id-from-spinner

Comment: ya, if i wan to do custom spinner, then how to do it??

Answer (score 1):

```
 prepareData();

    allusers.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // clicked item will be shown as spinner
            value = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            custid = position;
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });

 public void prepareData()
{
    users=databaseHelper.getAllUsers(user_id2);
    //adapter for spinner
    adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(AddMobRepairActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,android.R.id.text1,users);

    //attach adapter to spinner
    allusers.setAdapter();
}
```

Comment: Please explain a bit about your answer